# Cannot get rid of white section at the top of iPhone X emulator

Tags: react-native

I just started learning and building an app with react native. Never used xCode before but am using the iPhone X emulator. The login and register screens render fine by themselves. But as soon as I use react navigator, I get this white section at the top and I cannot get rid of it. Please help.

I added SafeAreaView and played around with the various settings but that does not help.

Here is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './components/pages/LoginScreen.js'
import RegisterScreen from './components/pages/RegisterScreen.js'

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea} forceInset={{ top: 'never' }}>
        <AppStackNavigator style={styles.container}/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator ({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen
}))

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
    marginVertical: 40,
  },
  safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
  }
});
```

[image: here is what it looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    const AppStackNavigator = createAppContainer(
      createStackNavigator({
        Login: {
          screen: LoginScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          },
        },
        Register: RegisterScreen,
      }),
);
```

-

```
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR }}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: -getStatusBarHeight() }}>
        {/* Content */}
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hend! That helped. However, now my button has shifted to the left despite me aligning content to the center. Any ideas how I can move it back to the middle?

Comment: Never mind. I used alignSelf: 'center' and it solved the problem.

Comment: @BVB09 glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-native-iphone-x-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iphone-x-helper)

Comment: I looked into it but couldn't come up with anything that might help. I am also fairly new to react native so not sure how I can play around with it.